# android studio tensorflow cpp build - undefined reference

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, tensorflow, native

I have downloaded tensorflow from ghit, 
I configure WORKSPACE file with my android sdk and android ndk.

I run ./configure from command line

and I build with buzel

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --cpu=armeabi-v7a --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --config=android --fat_apk_cpu=armeabi-v7a --verbose_failures
```

The build works fine.

When I go in Android Studio, I include my libtensorflow_inference.so in jnilibs folder and in CMakefile.txt I have include all directory of .h file and tendorflow dependences.

CMakefile.txt

```
#include header file
#TENSORFLOW
include_directories(${pathTensorflow})
#TENSORFLOW dependeces
include_directories(${pathToWorkspace}/downloads/nsync/public)
include_directories(${pathToWorkspace}/downloads/protobuf/src)
include_directories(${pathToWorkspace}/downloads/eigen)


#include tensorflow shared library
add_library( lib_TF SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_TF PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${pathToProject}/src/main/jnilibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libtensorflow_inference.so)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                  myLibcpp

                  lib_TF

                  ...
                  )
```

In my file cpp, I've insert this code

```
tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def;
```

But when I run make file I recive this error

```
Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Error:(100) undefined reference to 'tensorflow::GraphDef::GraphDef()'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, my cmake is setup the same as yours, this is the output:

> Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process cmake.exe with arguments {--build \app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86_64 --target native-lib}
>
> [1/2] Building CXX object native-lib.cpp.o
>
> [2/2] Linking CXX shared library libnative-lib.so
>
> FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && x86_64-linux-android-g++.exe  --sysroot=C:/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=23 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++14 -O0  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot C:/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-23/arch-x86_64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ..\native-lib.cpp.o  -llog ../libs/tf_libs/x86_64/libtensorflow_inference.so -latomic -lm "C:/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86_64/libgnustl_static.a" && cd ."
>
> \app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:15: error: undefined reference to 'TF_Version'
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

So it seems to be linking the library (-llog ../libs/tf_libs/x86_64/libtensorflow_inference.so) but cant find the symbols for some reason.

I cant find any information about what -llog does.

Ive tried with gcc and clang tool-chain.